# Object deforms/jumps off when using array+curve

Tags: modifiers

Im trying to make a railing using array + curve and in some turns the object rotates and deforms in a way i dont want. I feel like theres something wrong with the curve and its points but i have no idea.[image]
Help

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't have verical bars with an *Array + Curve* method, they will deform and tilt, but you can use this method instead:

Give the *Array + Curve* to a simple vertex instead (use the *Constant Offset* option of the *Array*):

[image]

Enable the *Instancing > Vertices* option of the vertex:

[image]

Parent the bar to the vertex (it won't rotate on Z but as yours seems to be a cylinder it won't be a problem):

[image]